# How to design a Credits Page

Tags: ios, credits

How create a view controller to show 'Credits' of the app. I am thinking about table view, but i cant figure how to animate it like the one they show in the end of movies.

Comment: Why not a text view and change the content offset. How exactly do you want it to look?

Comment: Yeah TextView would do it i think. Let me try this one.

Answer (score -1):

You can animate UILabel, put your credits in this. Set the coordinates to off the screen at the bottom, and then animate to off the screen at the top.

```
UILabel *credits = [[UILabel alloc] init];
credits.text=@"your text here, it's easier to do this in the interface builder though so you can add new lines";
credits.center=CGPointMake(someX, someYOffTheScreen);
[self.view addSubview:credits];
[UIView animateWithDuration:10 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{

        //make the frame somewhere off the screen
        credits.center=CGPointMake(someX, someYOffTheScreenOppositeEnd);



    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [credits removeFromSuperview];

    }];
```

where credits is the `UILabel`